# Testing tabaility with enzyme

Tags: reactjs, input, enzyme

I have a simple checkbox input I want to test it when user wants to tab into the checkbox and expect something to happen.

```
const CheckBox = () => (
 <input type="checkbox">
)
```

Test case:

```
describe("tabability", ()=> {
 it("tab into the input",()=>{
  const testForm = mount(
    <div>
      <input type="text" id="textInput" />
      <CheckBox id="checkBox" />
    </div>
  );

  const textInput = testForm.find("textInput");
  textInput.simulate("keypress", {key: "Tab"});
 })
})
```

But It seems to fail to find the text input.  my `textInput` variable is pointing to testForm.  What can I do to assigned input text to a variable and assign checkbox to a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be

```
...
const textInput = testForm.find("#textInput");
...
```

same goes for the checkbox